# Julia: Subset data frame

Tags: julia

I had two tab delimited files; one with the data, and the second one with the names of the columns that I am interested in. I want to subset the data frame so that it only has my columns of interest. Here is my code:

```
dat1 = DataFrame(CSV.File("data.txt"))
hdr = Symbol(readdlm("header.txt",'\t'))
```

which gives

```
julia> dat1
4×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ chr    │ pos   │ alt    │ ref    │ cadd    │
│     │ String │ Int64 │ String │ String │ Float64 │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ chr1   │ 1234  │ A      │ T      │ 23.4    │
│ 2   │ chr2   │ 1234  │ C      │ G      │ 5.4     │
│ 3   │ chr2   │ 1234  │ G      │ C      │ 11.0    │
│ 4   │ chr5   │ 3216  │ A      │ T      │ 3.0     │

julia> hdr
Symbol("Any[\"pos\" \"alt\"]")
```

However, I get an error if I try to subset with:

```
julia> dat2 = dat1[ :, :hdr]
```

What would be the correct way to subset? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
hdr = vec(readdlm("header.txt",'\t'))
dat2 = dat1[:, hdr]
```

or for the second step

```
dat2 = select(df1, hdr)
```

What is important here is hat `hdr` should be a vector of strings.

You could also have written:

```
dat2 = select(df1, readdlm("header.txt",'\t')...)
```

splatting the contents of the matrix (strings holding column names) as positional arguments.